# Are there infinitly growing aliquote sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series

An aliquot sequence is a sequence of positive integers in which each term is the sum of the proper divisors of the previous term.

Those can be
(1) Sequences ending in 1: 9->4->3->1
(2) Cycles
   (2.1) of size 1: 6
   (2.2) of size 2: 220-284

Are there sequences that grow arbitrary large?

Answer (score 2):

It isn't known. [The Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliquot_sequence) has a lot of this information, in addition to the sequence of numbers for which the Aliquot sequence isn't known:

$$276, 306, 396, 552, 564, 660, 696, 780, 828, 888, 966, 996, ...$$

which is [A131884](http://oeis.org/A131884) in the OEIS. In addition, [factordb](http://factordb.com) has a lot of Aliquot sequences.

In terms of whether one would be expected to exist, it depends how you look at it. One can observe that whenever $6|n$, the next term in $n$'s aliquot sequence is $>n$, so if numbers continue to have enough $2$s and $3$s in them then the sequence will continually increase. However, one can also make the argument that it is likely that eventually the sequence will have to decrease (I haven't seen the heuristic on it, if there is one). The bottom line is that we really have no idea.

Comment: Is there a proven infinite sequence? Is there a reason to believe such sequence would or would not exist?

Comment: @Stepan Read the first sentence of my answer. I'll add more for the second question in a bit.